# Implementing React native maps with redux

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, expo, react-native-maps

Can anyone recommend me some articles / docs or (better yet) tutorials on a comprehensive implementation of Redux with React-Native-Maps? I am currrently working on a project that would requires such.
I want to have the global state of the user location and destination.
Also, I want to be able to multiple map render, with different destinations. 
I assume I should be able to achieve this with redux, however my knowledge of redux is quite basic, like the todo app example.
Kindly advice otherwise or share your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

I think its best if you start with getting a practical understanding of Redux, the TODO app will not take you far. start with [this](https://www.valentinog.com/blog/redux/)

Once you are comfortable with Redux, [this](https://github.com/mbeaudru/react-native-sample) is a repo that integrates react native maps, (camera as a bonus) and react Redux application.

Hope this Helps!